# Have Kenneth Muir's poems ever been published as a collection?

Tags: poetry, textual-history, kenneth-muir

[Kenneth Muir](https://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/obituary-professor-kenneth-muir-5598317.html) (1907–1996) was an eminent and very productive Shakespeare scholar. Wikipedia has a [short article about him](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Muir_(scholar)) that leaves out many lesser-known facts:

- he directed a number of plays, including *Troilus and Cressida* (which he also edited for the [Oxford Shakespeare](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/troilus-and-cressida-the-oxford-shakespeare-9780199536535));
- he translated at least one of Racine's plays;
- in the 1930s, he knew poets such as [Stephen Spender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Spender) and [W. H. Auden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._H._Auden),
- in 1933, Oxford University Press published a volume of his poems: [*The Nettle and the Flower*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/nettle-and-the-flower-and-other-poems/oclc/1494580&referer=brief_results) (which contained a poem dedicated to W. H. Auden),
- he later published hundreds of poems in magazines.

In spite of the research I have done, I have not been able to find an edition or even an anthology of Kenneth Muir's poetry. In the absence of that, has anybody ever compiled a bibliography listing his poems?

Comment: A note to anyone researching this question: make sure you get the right Kenneth Muir (there's more than one notable person with this name even in the world of literature), and beware of collections which were merely *edited* by KM rather than *written* by him.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://www.britac.ac.uk/sites/default/files/97p393.pdf) ("Kenneth Muir", *Proceedings of the British Academy* 97 (1998), pp. 393–409):

> There is a selective bibliography of Kenneth Muir’s writings, 1937–79, in
>   the book of essays in his honour, *Shakespeare’s Styles*, ed. Philip Edwards, Inga-Stina Ewbank, and  G. K. Hunter (Cambridge, 1980). A more comprehensive bibliography  will  appear  in  his  Autobiography, forthcoming  from Liverpool University Press.

I found the book *Shakespeare's Styles: Essays in honour of Kenneth Muir* on [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Shakespeare_s_Styles.html?id=nDB1QgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y), but there's no preview so that I can check the bibliography. His autobiography is even harder to track down - Google seems to have no record of it.

OK, this is only a signpost to a signpost, but it's the best I've been able to find in the way of a bibliography. Muir's poems don't seem to have been put together in any anthology or collection. I've even searched the online catalogue of one of the [UK legal deposit libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_deposit#United_Kingdom), without success.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article, which I didn't know. (Blame it on too many "John Kenneth Muir" search engine hits.) I suspect that the autobiography was never published in the end; I'll contact Liverpool Uni Press. And I'll see if I can get hold of a copy of *Shakespeare's Styles*, even though the bibliography may focus on Muir's academic work.

Comment: According to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/LivUniPress/status/951454288546553863), Liverpool University Press hasn't published Muir's autobiography.